# word search puzzle generator written in python 3 gets caught in an infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, infinite-loop

So I started to create a word search generator in Python 3 with the least complexity possible. I ended up with the following code and hope to find out where I need to improve.

**The issue**:
The main issue is that the code might get stuck in an infinite loop trying to put the last word in the puzzle. My aim is to make the code more efficient by avoiding that.

The main file (**wsg.py**) and the word database (**n_words.txt**) are available at:

https://github.com/mannysayah/wordsearchpuzzle_py3

Here's how **wsg.py** looks:

```
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
    
# How many meaningful words should take up the puzzle
make_up_total = 0.70
    
# Grid size 
width = 10
height = 10
    
# Probabilities
ph = 0.3
pd = 0.3
pv = 0.4
    
total_words_letters = int(width * height * make_up_total)
filename = 'n_words.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.readlines()
#  remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
data = [x.strip() for x in data] 
list_of_all_words = []
for x in data:
    if len(x) < width and len(x) < height:
        list_of_all_words.append(x)
    
data = list_of_all_words
total_take = 0
word_list = []
    
while total_take < total_words_letters - 4:
    item = random.choice(data)
    if len(item) < total_words_letters - total_take:
        word_list.append(item)
        total_take += len(item)
    
print(word_list)
puzzle = np.zeros((width, height)).astype(int).astype(str)
directions = [[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
    
def existing_word(d,word):
    xsize = width if d[0] == 0 else width - len(word)
    ysize = width if d[1] == 0 else height - len(word)
    x = random.randrange(0,xsize)
    y = random.randrange(0,ysize)
    temp_word = []
    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        temp_word.append(str(puzzle[y+d[1]*i][x+d[0]*i]))
    return("".join(temp_word),x,y)
        
def compare_them(w1, w2):
    comp = []
    for i,j in zip(w1, w2):
        if j == "0":
            comp.append("Zero")
        else:
            if i == j:
                comp.append("Match")
            else:
                comp.append(False)
    if ( comp.count("Match") <= 1 and comp.count(False) == 0 ):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def fill_with_rand(puzzle,w,h):
    mask = ([puzzle == "0"])
    new_puzzle = np.copy(puzzle)
    alpha_puzzle = np.copy([[random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(0,w)] for j in range(0,h)])
    new_puzzle[tuple(mask)] = alpha_puzzle[tuple(mask)]
    return new_puzzle
    
for word in word_list:
    while (True):
        word = random.choice([word, word[::-1]]) # word can be backwards
        d = np.random.choice([0,1,2],p=[ph,pv,pd]) # Take a random choice of [0,1,2]
        d = directions[d] # now take that out of [directions]
        from_puzzle = existing_word(d, word) # now take an empty space from the puzzle with the same length as the word
        x = from_puzzle[1]
        y = from_puzzle[2]
        if compare_them(word, from_puzzle[0]):
            for i in range(0,len(word)):
                puzzle[y+d[1]*i][x+d[0]*i] = word[i]
            break
            
print(fill_with_rand(puzzle, width, height))
```

Comment: You mention an infinite loop possibility. Does or doesn't the code currently work as intended?

Comment: It works fine when there are lots of possible answers. But (obviously) it gets harder when it gets more complicated. Like when you want the whole puzzle filled with meaningful words (no random letters). I understand that my code needs an algorithm to find the best solution but before that, I would like to add a handy flow control.  I don't want to add an algorithm here. Just to make the code escape after N attempts and output something like **"The best result: X out of S words are successfully added to the puzzle after N attempts."**

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data  that produces your problem. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, pretty neat! But I guess your assumption was this is part of a package. But this code is standalone and the issue (as I explained in the question) is not an output or caused by any specific input.  Cheers

Comment: So basically this is an elaborate version of "How do I solve the halting problem?". You [can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). This is literally one of the oldest proofs in computer science.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the wiki. But I believe it's not the issue. There is something wrong with the way I've written that loop and I (and almost everyone else who tested the code) still can't figure out what. Cheers